# ng-repeat sorting for price inappropriate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am using angular `ng-repeat` with `orderBy` for a product catalogue page to order the products according to select change.

Here `orderBy` name is working fine but when it comes to price it order like this `1,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` because its checking only first value.

I need the result like this `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14`

**select html**

```
<select ng-model="sortFilter" ng-init="sortFilter='name'">
    <option value="name">Default</option>
    <option value="price">Price Low to High</option>
    <option value="-price">Price High to Low</option>
</select>
```

**products html**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:sortFilter">
    <div class="product_box clearfix">
        <div class="product_img">
            <img src="images/{{product.imgLink}}">
        </div>
        <div class="product_right">
            <div class="product_details">
                <p class="product_name">{{product.name}}</p>
                <p class="product_price">{{product.price}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buy_product">
                <p><a href="{{product.link}}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Buy Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**product ng-repeat code**

```
$scope.products = [
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 14.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 13.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 12.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 11.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 10.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 9.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 8.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 7.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 6.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'eWingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 5.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'dWingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 4.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'cWingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 3.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'bWingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 2.00', link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'aWingtip Congnac Oxford', price: '$ 1.00', link: '#'},
];
```

Comment: This is because the price key is a string, not a number. Is there any chance you can extract the price as a numeric value and create a separate key price_sort and then sort using that without actually showing it to the user?

Comment: can you help me with some code?

Comment: Can you add the ng-repeat code that you have right now?

Comment: oops it was there only with one missing line...updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are dealing with currency/numbers you should store the datatype of type number.

There is then no need to parse the price!

You can then easily display/calculate/sort the data how you would like without any issues as it is in the correct format.

Change your price properties to numbers:

```
$scope.products = [
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 14, link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 13, link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 12, link: '#'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 11, link: '#'},
...
];
```

And then either:

```
<p class="product_price">${{product.price}}</p>
```

Or using the [currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency):

```
<p class="product_price">{{product.price | currency: '$'}}</p>
```

Comment: What if he is storing the price as a string inside of a database and is not using a static array? He asked that we work with the data he provided, not try to change what he currently has. If he could change his values to a numeric type then this is definitely a better way to go.

Comment: He did not say he is storing the price as a string in a database. He did post a static array. He did not ask to work with the data he provided. He said "I need the result like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14". Having the correct data type for the job in the first place is not a bad solution. If the data is stored as a string in the database then perhaps updating the data in the database might be appropriate. Imo it's a more sensible approach to use the correct data type and make use of a service that already exists.

Comment: Well my bad because i was not aware that prices should be stored as number not strings and this is the easiest way to do this. Thanks for this knowledge i can change my code this way this is the actual way to do this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to:

```
<select ng-model="sortFilter" ng-init="sortFilter='name'">
    <option value="name">Default</option>
    <option value="sort_price">Price Low to High</option>
    <option value="-sort_price">Price High to Low</option>
</select>
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:sortFilter" ng-init="product.sort_price = parsePriceToFloat(product.price)">
    <div class="product_box clearfix">
        <div class="product_img">
            <img src="images/{{product.imgLink}}">
        </div>
        <div class="product_right">
            <div class="product_details">
                <p class="product_name">{{product.name}}</p>
                <p class="product_price">{{product.price}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buy_product">
                <p><a href="{{product.link}}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Buy Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add a function inside of your controller:

```
$scope.parsePriceToFloat = function(price) {
    return Number(String(price).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
}
```

That parsePriceToFloat function is going to remove any non-numeric values and return a Number type which can then be sorted by your orderBy code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your price to *number*. You can call **parseInt(price)**, to do this quickly.

Comment: maybe your answer would be good but please explain its incomplete for me as of now.